# Where to find source code of Android DDMS tool -- Alocation Tracker?

Tags: android, memory-management

can anybody tell me where to find the source code of Allocation Tracker, the memory trace tool in Android DDMS?(http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.ddmlib/ddmlib/r16/com/android/ddmlib/Client.java#Client.requestAllocationDetails%28%29)

Or, are there any other ways to analysis the memory allocation and find out **how much memory each class uses within an Android app/process**?

Comment: I guess that this tool is not open source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The allocation-tracker page (https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/allocation-tracker/index.html) said that  "7 .... Note that allocations are logged on the device, and the data file is transferred to the host computer, parsed for information, and displayed."  Maybe I could get the data file and do something with it.